# Register-Scheduledjob for mandatory profile users

Tags: powershell

I have a PowerShell script that I want to run in the background every few minutes. Creating a scheduled task for this script doesn’t work, because even when run with –windowstyle hidden, there is still a brief flash of the PowerShell box, which we cannot have. I have found that running this script as a PowerShell scheduled job works with no visual clues at all.

The scheduled jobs appear to store relevant information in the location %APPDATA%\Local\Microsoft\Windows\PowerShell. The problem I am facing is that we are using mandatory profiles for our users on Windows 10 PCs, so anything stored in the user’s profile disappears when they log out. This means that the scheduled job has to be recreated every time the user logs in, but the users do not have the permissions necessary to create the job.

I have created a PowerShell script that creates the necessary job, but it requires elevation to work.
My first thought was to create a scheduled task that runs at log on. This task would then launch the script to create the scheduled job. I tried this using GPO so the task would be created and run with the system account, but I am still not getting the results I am looking for.

When I successfully create the job as an admin and then export to XML, I see the reference to the %APPDATA% location. Is there a way to import the scheduled job from an xml file that has been edited to refer to a different store? Is there a way to register the job and have it use a different disk space instead of %APPDATA%?

Here is the script to create the job:

```
$start = (get-date)+(New-TimeSpan -Minutes 10)
$trigger = New-JobTrigger -at $start -once -RepetitionInterval (New-TimeSpan -Minutes 5) -RepeatIndefinitely

Register-ScheduledJob -Name "JobName" -Trigger $trigger -ScriptBlock { *JobScriptGoesHere* }
```

Comment: Why are you not making this part of the domain user logon script via GPO? Scheduled tasks are just xml file, thus you can copy and save them wherever you want and import as needed.

Comment: Logon scripts run in the user's context. These users do not have the permissions necessary to create the scheduled job. It has to be a PowerShell scheduled job rather than a regular scheduled task so it can run completely in the background with absolutely no visual indication.

Comment: Granted, then why not set it a computer startup script task?

Comment: As far as I can tell, PowerShell scheduled jobs store the actual script in a user's AppData\Local folder. All profile folders are removed when the user logs off. I need to find a way to store the script elsewhere. This script must run as a scheduled job, because it will run every 5 minutes and there can be no indication to the user that anything is happening. If I use a startup script to create the job, it does not get created. I assume this is because there is no AppData folder for the System account

Comment: The default Public profile is never removed. It's what all other profiles are based on. You can store anything there, and use that to become part of any new profile create later.

Comment: I tried that, but the job does not carry over to the new profiles. The files come over to the new profiles, but the job does not.